# duplicate an existing tree branch and store it into the database

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, jstree

Hallöschen everyone,

i'm having a hierarchical array which i'm getting from jsTree when I copy+paste a node and I want to insert the new tree branch into database.

My table has an adjacency list structure with the three fields 'id','text','parent_id'.

The structure can be like below or more nested. I did't figured out how to keep track of the parent so to know which children belong to which parent as I walk the array recursively.

What could be the cleanest approach?

```
Array(
  [id] => 1
  [text] => 'a'
  [children] 
    =>Array(
       [0] => Array
           (
             [id] => 2
             [text] => 'b'
             [children] => []
            )

       [1] => Array
            (
             [id] => 3
             [text] => 'c'
             [children] => Array(
                    [0] => Array(
                                 [id] => 4
                                 [text] =>''
                                 [children]=>[]
                                 )
                                 )
            )
     )
   )
```

So the final sollution that works for me is this one

```
function insertRows($data, $parent_id)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($value['text']))
            // here insert the the $value['text'] and get the generated $id

        if (isset($value['children'])) {
            insertRows($value['children'], $id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, not sure what the question is, but assuming that the first level is the parent can't you just do `$parent = $array['id'];` ?

Comment: I'm trying to duplicate the branch. So it requires inserting the first node, get the new created id and create it's children with this id as parent_id

Comment: but what if I have 3 nodes on the same level? I'm inserting 1'st, 2'nd, 3'th and if i go next to insert children of the 1'st I don't have the ID of the 1'st anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To duplicate the dataset try this:

```
function insertRows($array, $parentId = null)
{
    /** @var PDO $pdo  */
    global $pdo;

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        // Add text and parent id to table.
        $pdo->query('INSERT INTO table SET text = "' . $value['text'] . '", parent_id = ' . $parentId);

        if (is_array($value['children'])) {
            insertRows($value['children'], $pdo->lastInsertId());
        }
    }
}
```

Its untested an similar to pseudocode. Its more a hint.

Comment: I am trying to insert the branch as new records with new id's. In other words I.m duplicating the branch.

Comment: I have edited my answer. may this help you. It rely's on using autoincrement ids for the column `id`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped :D

Answer (score 0):

**You can have third index as parent_id and for root element make parent_id as 0 and in thier respective children put parent_id as id of parent.**

```
for root element :

Array(
    [id] => 1,
    [text] => 'a',
    [parent_id] => 0
);

for 1st  child it would be like 

Array(
    [id] => 2,
    [text] => 'a',
    [parent_id] => 1
);
```